# jquery how to check date is less than current date

Tags: jquery, date

How can i check the date picker date which are selected is less than current date.

My date picker formate is **[MON d,YYYY]** Like **[Feb 6, 2012]**,

if i pick up old date in textbox how can i check this date is less than current date.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/492994/compare-2-dates-with-javascript

Answer (score 3):

Use `$.datepicker.parseDate(format, string)` to turn your date in to JavaScript Date, get current date by `var now = new Date();`

After that, You can just use `<` operator to check whether the date picked is less than the current date.

EDIT: Assuming you are using jquery ui date picker

Comment: Are you assuming that the OP is using a certain datepicker?

Comment: @alex - edited my answer, I assumed it to be jquery ui date picker, Thanks!

Comment: The comparison operator does not compare dates, it compares exact time.

Comment: MY code     var str = $("#txtinvdate").val(); $.datepicker.parseDate('yy-mm-dd', str) .its not working...

Comment: @vims - is there any error? is your 'str' value is in the format 'yy-mm-dd'?

Answer (score 2):

This seems to do the trick...

```
var isFutureDate = new Date < new Date(
                               str
                               .match(/^\[(\w{3})\s(\d+),\s(\d{4})\]$/)
                               .slice(1)
                               .join(' ')
                              );
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KFEaW/).

This creates a new `Date` object which defaults to the current client time, and then constructs a second `Date` object passing a modified version of your user input which can be parsed by the `Date` constructor. The `<` operators calls the `valueOf()` of both dates, which returns the milliseconds since the Unix epoch (equivalent of calling `getTime()`).

You could take into account leading and trailing whitespace on the input by using `$.trim()`  or wrapping the regex with `\s*`.

You could swap `new Date` with `$.now()`, which is slightly fewer characters